# Angular CLI with backend api in the same project

Tags: angular

So I want to write an app in Visual Studio using Angular for frontend and .NET for the backend. What's the best practice to do that, while the project is still in the same project?

Comment: Are you creating a .Net core project?

Comment: I'm creating ASP.NET web application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using angular cli to create new angular app. Now you can find cli's documentation on angular.io which is awesome! Also, please go through the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

Comment: I know about the quickstart, but you can't use CLI with it if I'm correct.

Comment: if i got your question right, yes you can create a fresh new project using cli, that's one of the very important function of this command line tool, to create projects, components, services without much hassle. Have you checked https://cli.angular.io/ ?

Comment: You didn't, I want to make use of Angular CLI, but you can't with only quickstart files.

Comment: you can download the cli globally using npm install -g @angular/cli and create new project using ng new my-dream-app. Now my-dream-app is configured with cli. If this does not answer your question, can you relate your question to this example or provide any other example you think will provide precise idea of your question?